# How to best create a jQuery Slider to display a native wordpress gallery?

Tags: plugins, jquery

It seems there must be a plugin for this, but I can't find it. I'd like to enable a jQuery slider in a post, using the images I've added to the gallery for that post. Does anyone know of a plugin?

And if not, what would be the smartest way to implement this? Again it's important that it calls from that posts gallery - using the native WordPress gallery.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found this in the meantime:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smooth-gallery-replacement/
and this paid plugin (which I haven't tried yet):
http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-gallery-shortcode/116049

Anything else? Anything better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a couple tutorials on how to make a dynamic jQuery featured post slider with Wordpress, here is my best one which is the most popular post on my site, in case you're interested in trying it out.

http://new2wp.com/pro/part-3-making-a-dynamic-wordpress-jquery-featured-post-slider-tutorial-finale/